# Can I install any Debian or Ubuntu application on Kali Linux?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, kali-linux, deb, ppa

I want to know if it is possible to install a Debian application (or an Ubuntu PPA) that is not in the Kali repository especially because I want to install a bitcoin wallet ([How can I install a bitcoin wallet on Kali Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167710/how-can-i-install-a-bitcoin-wallet-on-kali-linux) and [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32442/how-can-i-install-a-bitcoin-wallet-on-kali-linux))
If Kali Linux is based on Debian,doesn't it mean that after doing the correct settings and probably other modifications you can install apps from the Debian repository?
Also,I would like to know if Ubuntu PPAs can be added to Kali too and if they can,what do I need to do in order for the PPA to work?
I am using Kali Linux 1.0.9 64-bit on my laptop.

Comment: Did you try it? `deb` *should* tell you if you can install a program or not. I'm not a Debian guy, but give it a try and learn. A quick web search will show how to add repos.

Comment: @SailorCire that is spectacularly bad advice actually. Any apt-based distro can install .deb packages but that doesn't mean that it won't cause problems. In fact, Debian packages are often not compatible with Ubuntu-based distributions and vice versa. Mixing repositories across distributions can lead to deep dependency hell and a broken system.

Comment: @terdon You're telling me that debian based package managers don't keep track if it can satisfy a package requirement? If they can see those requirements and check for conflicts then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @terdon Sorry, the first response was too sharp and that wasn't my goal. My point is, a package manager should be able to check if it can install a program (check for requirements and conflicts). If it can't satisfy them, then it shouldn't install it (without a force option). In the original question, if that install fails from mixing repos, then the answer to the original question is no. I agree, you can get deep into a dependency hell; however, when `apt-get` or whatever throws a fit that it can't meet dependencies because foo-x.y isn't available then the question gets answered.

Comment: @SailorCire but that's the problem. Consider this: 1) you add a PPA to Debian 2) you install something from it which depends on a newer glibc than you have installed 3) this dependency also updates your glibc to the version on the PPA 4) you have a broken system. The problem is that very often `apt` will not throw a fit since as far as it's concerned everything is covered. It can't know that this update will break things, all its dependencies are fine. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11351) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/264766/85695)

Comment: @terdon except that, if a newer version of glibc already exists it would be updated anyway unless the newer version is provided by the ppa. If a user is purposely not updating a version of glibc or whatever they should already have apt-mark in use to prevent this. apt-get will not make that upgrade without user verification, it won't be listed as an error but it will be listed. Anyway, that could be said of any package that uses the newest version of glibc as a dependency.

Comment: @mchid I'm talking about the case where it is provided by the ppa. _That_ can break the system.

Comment: @terdon yes, but that is quite rare for a ppa to provide a package like that for good reason. This is also why users should always inspect a ppa before installing blindly.

Comment: @mchid that is just one of the many different scenarios that can break your system if you use a repository not specifically designed for that system. That's also the official position of the relevant distributions. For example Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MarkShuttleworth#What_about_binary_compatibility_between_distributions.3F. The point is that unless you know what you're doing, you shouldn't use Debian repos on Ubuntu or vice versa. Yes, you can sometimes do it but i) it's not a good idea ii) it can be risky and iii) it is best left to expert users.

Comment: The bitcoin ppa is not compatable. Your libboost versions are at 1.49.0 and precise asks for 1.46.1, trusty and utopic ask for versions > 1.50.0.

Comment: @terdon I agree with that and it should be advised that there can be consequences but the OP asked "can I" and not "should I". It sounds like he/she is trying to learn how to be an expert user.

Comment: @mchid yes, and my comment, as I'm sure you noticed, was not directed at the OP and was not an answer to the question. It was intended only to qualify the first comment left to the OP which suggested blindly attempting to install. That is dangerous advice and _that_ is what I wanted to point out.